# Calculating polynomial value by difference method

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Apologies if this is a basic question!

I am taking an online course, introduction to computer science. In one of the lectures, the professor mentions that computers can calculate the value of polynomial by taking the difference.

For example, for polynomial $P(x)=3x^2-2x+1,x\in\mathbb{Z}$, the computer can calculate the value of this polynomial by several initial values.

We define the difference of first-order $\Delta P(x)$ as $P(x)-P(x-1)$ and the difference of second-order $\Delta^2P(x)$ as $\Delta P(x)-\Delta P(x-1)$. For the previous example, we have following table.

| $ x$ | $P(x)$ | $\Delta P(x)$ | $\Delta^2 P(x)$ | $P(x)+\Delta P(x)+\Delta^2 P(x)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 9 | 7 |  |  |
| 3 | 22 | 13 | 6 | 41 |
| 4 | 41 | 19 | 6 | 66 |
| 5 | 66 | 25 | 6 | 97 |
| 6 | 97 | 31 | 6 | 134 |
| 7 | 134 | 37 | 6 | 177 |
| 8 | 177 | 43 | 6 | 226 |
| 9 | 226 | 49 | 6 | 281 |
| 10 | 281 | 55 | 6 | 342 |
| 11 | 342 | 61 | 6 | 409 |
| 12 | 409 | 67 | 6 | 482 |
| 13 | 482 | 73 | 6 | 561 |
| 14 | 561 | 79 | 6 | 646 |
| 15 | 646 | 85 | 6 | 737 |
| 16 | 737 | 91 | 6 | 834 |
| 17 | 834 | 97 | 6 | 937 |
| 18 | 937 | 103 | 6 | 1046 |
| 19 | 1046 | 109 | 6 | 1161 |
| 20 | 1161 | 115 | 6 | 1282 |
| 21 | 1282 | 121 | 6 | 1409 |
| 22 | 1409 | 127 | 6 | 1542 |
| 23 | 1542 | 133 | 6 | 1681 |
| 24 | 1681 | 139 | 6 | 1826 |
| 25 | 1826 | 145 | 6 |  |

We notice that it seems like $P(x)=P(x-1)+\Delta P(x-1)+\Delta^2 P(x-1)$. After trying some other examples, I find out it seems like for a polynomial with rank $r$, $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^r\Delta^iP(x)$. We define $P(x)=\Delta^0P(x)$. I want to prove it mathematically. The following is what I tried.

I tried to expand $\sum_{i=0}^r\Delta^iP(x)$. I began with several trivial cases.
\begin{align*}\Delta^0P(x)&=P(x)\\\Delta^1P(x)&=P(x)-P(x-1)\\\Delta^2P(x)&=\Delta^1P(x)-\Delta^1P(x-1)\\&=P(x)-P(x-1)-(P(x-1)-P(x-2))\\&=P(x)-2P(x-1)+P(x-2)\\\Delta^3P(x)&=\Delta^2P(x)-\Delta^2P(x-1)\\&=P(x)-2P(x-1)+P(x-2)-(P(x-1)-2P(x-2)+P(x-3))\\&=P(x)-3P(x-1)+3P(x-2)-P(x-3)\end{align*}

Until now, I notice that with the power of difference going up, we just move the coefficients of the previous one rightward, change the sign and add it with the previous coefficients. And the coefficients are somehow related to Pascal's Triangle. So I think the difference of r-order will be
\begin{align*}\Delta^rP(x)&=(-1)^0C_n^0P(x)+(-1)^1C_n^1P(x-1)+\cdots+(-1)^rC_n^rP(x-r)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^i(-1)^iC_n^iP(x-i)\end{align*}
And according to Pascal's Triangle, we can get the sum of different order of difference easily.
$$\sum_{i=0}^r\Delta^iP(x)=(-1)^0C_{r+1}^1P(x)+(-1)^1C_{r+1}^2P(x-1)+\cdots+(-1)^rC_{r+1}^{r+1}P(x-r)$$
However, I don't know how to relate this expression to $P(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is known as *Newton's Method of Finite Differences*. It is a way of determining the value of a polynomial using several **consecutive** points.

This is easier to think about if you start with a bit of a calculus approach. What you have stumbled upon here is the fact that you can express the $n$-th derivative of a function can be expressed using a backwards difference formula. That is to say, given a function $f(x)$, we have that
$$\begin{align*}f'(x) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x - h)}{h}\\
f''(x) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - 2f(x - h) + f(x - 2h)}{h^2}\\
&\vdots\\
f^{(n)}(x) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} f(x-ih)}{h^n}.\\
\end{align*}$$
Now let's consider what happens when we look at a polynomial equation. The term $\Delta^i P(x)$ gives us the "change in the polynomial up to the $i$-th order." That is to say, it is giving us something like information for the $i$-th derivative of the polynomial. So, if we have a polynomial of degree $r$, we would expect that the $r$-th difference to be a constant, and this is, in fact, the case! In your example, you have a polynomial of degree 2, and $\Delta^2P(x) = 6$ which is the second derivative of $P(x)$.

Now, we need to be a little careful, since the intermediate differences are not giving us exactly the value of the derivative at the given point, but I think that this perspective gives us some good intuition to justify why this will always work. The important thing here is that the $r$-th difference for a degree $r$ polynomial will always be constant, and once we have figured that out, we can then work through the table in the opposite direction to fill in what the values should be. Let us consider the table that you have worked out here

| $ x$ | $P(x)$ | $\Delta P(x)$ | $\Delta^2 P(x)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 2 | 9 | 7 |  |
| 3 | 22 | 13 | 6 |
| 4 | 41 | 19 | 6 |

To find the value of $P(4)$ we know that $\Delta^2 P(3) = 6 = \Delta^2 P(4)$, $\Delta P(3) + \Delta^2 P(4) = 13 + 6 = \Delta P(4)$, and we can then get that $P(3) + \Delta P(4) = 22 + 19 = 41 = P(4) $. With a little bit of algebraic finagling, we can generalize this method of "working backwards" to get that

$$P(x + 1) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^r \Delta^i P(x)$$

which I believe you observed in your original posting. I hope that helps!